# Try catch OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

Почему не перехватывается exception, поставил в двух местах catch все равно программа падает и указывает на

```
Bitmap  image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSettings.getString(Const.directory, "") + "/" + file.getName(), bmOptions);
```

ошибка  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`:

```
          try {
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            Bitmap  image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSettings.getString(Const.directory, "") + "/" + file.getName(), bmOptions);
                            if (Picture.getCameraPhotoOrientation(file) !=0) {
                                image = Picture.rotateBitmap(image, Picture.getCameraPhotoOrientation(file));
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                toast( "Exception " + e + "");
            }
```

Comment: `catch(Throwable e){}` - против лома нет приёма!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таким образом перехватить не получится, потому что OutOfMemoryError это не Exception, а Error. Попробуй перехватить такой конструкцией:

```
try{
   // Запрос 
} catch (OutOfMemoryError E){
   // Обработка ошибки
}
```

Хороший пример по теме [тут](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-exceptions).

Answer (score 4):

Если вы посмотрите [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html), т обнаружите, что `OutOfMemoryError` не является исключением, а ошибкой JVM, т.е. наследуется не от `Exception`,  а от `Error`, поэтому ваш catch его не поймает.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще, перехватывать Error - плохая практика. Если у вас в программе Error - то что-то не так с JVM, с окружением. 
Да и какой смысл перехватывать OutOfMemory? Что вы дальше будете делать, если у вас полностью heap заполнен?

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к другим ответам: исключение, возникающее в потоке, не будет доставлено в точку, где поток запускается. Хотя бы потому, что код, запускающий поток, вполне имеет право отработать и завершиться к тому моменту, когда в потоке возникнет исключение.

Ловите исключения в коде, бегущем *в* потоке, и никак иначе.

Поэтому внешний try/catch не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Перехват Error - это очень плохая практика ([смотрим документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)). И если в случае простых приложений (или наглядного пособия) это хоть как то можно оправдать, то в любом мало-мальски серьёзном приложении это может вызвать дополнительные проблемы.

Как пример - нет никакой гарантии, что Application Server корректно обработает все свои try-catch блоки, то есть вполне вероятна ситуация, что вы то коректно поймали и обработали ошибку, а вот App Server этого сделать не смог. Как итог - сложнодиагностируемая утечка ресурсов.

UPD: В Weblogic есть специальные настройки, позволяющие после OOM автоматически рестартовать сервер [Exit on Out of Memory Exceptions](http://docs.tpu.ru/docs/oracle/en/fmw/11.1.1.6.0/web.1111/e13701/overload.htm)

> This feature allows you to minimize the impact of the out of memory condition—automatic shutdown helps avoid application instability, and you can configure Node Manager or another high availability (HA) tool to automatically restart WebLogic Server, minimizing down-time

Собственно, это говорит о том, что нет гарантии корректной работы Application после ООМ.

Comment: Если бы вы привели какую-нибудь ссылку насчёт поведения Application Server'а, это повысило бы ценность информации.